# Syntax difference between MAMP and Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, mamp, lamp

I have the following function to account for Sundays in business day calculations. It works on my test server which is MAMP running on a Mac. When I move the code to an Ubuntu server running LAMP, it stops working (manifested as the page not loading anything).

I can't work out why, and have tried all different combinations of single quotes and double quotes.

The function is:-

```
// function to account for Sundays, and public holidays. Add holiday dates in $holidayDays variable
function get_next_business_date($from, $days) {
$workingDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; # date format = N (1 = Monday, ...)
$holidayDays = ["*-12-25","*-12-26", "*-01-01", "2014-12-24"]; # variable and fixed holidays

$from = new DateTime($from);
while ($days) {
    $from->modify("+1 day");
    if (!in_array($from->format('N'), $workingDays)) continue;
    if (in_array($from->format('Y-m-d'), $holidayDays)) continue;
    if (in_array($from->format('*-m-d'), $holidayDays)) continue;
    $days--;
}
return $from->format("Y-m-d"); #  or just return DateTime object
}

$today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("today"));
$tomorrow = get_next_business_date("today", 1);
$twodays = get_next_business_date("today", 2);
$yesterday  =   date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));
```

I'm lost as to why this could be.

Comment: The "page not loading anything" or "white screen of death" in PHP means you need to check your error log. Always when developing and testing code, use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script. The error will be detailed out.

Comment: Are you sure that it is something to do with this function? Perhaps it is a permissions issue instead?

Comment: review /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: The array literals `[]` as in `$workingDays = [...]` require PHP 5.4 or later. My suspicion is your server is 5.3. You'll probably need to declare those via `array()`

Comment: In this day and age of virtualboxes and vagrant, I can't understand why anybody needs to develop in a different environment, and with different software versions/extensions than the intended production servers

Comment: Thanks all. It's the white screen of death. Will start error checking as per Michael's suggestion. Only thought about it being the function as the page worked fine until I added the function. Will check permissions though. Unfortunately I'm not in control of the boxes I use. I would prefer a linux box to use as my test environment however it was all I could do to get a test environment in the first place, let alone another linux box :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Yup, it's a version issue. As you suspected it's 5.3 on the live server, and 5.5 on the test box. I hadn't noticed this before, and will upgrade the server version (assuming that's relatively straight forward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the responses in the various comments, this was a server version issue. The version of PHP on my test box was more recent than the version on the live.

If it's of any use, I am using MAMP on a Mac Mini as my test environment which had 5.5.3, and LAMP on an UBUNTU 12.04 server box which had 5.3. I didn't want to upgrade the Ubuntu version, just the PHP version and did so as per this http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-5-3-php-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Things to be aware of (if you don't know) are that the default directory for your php code will change from /var/www to /var/www/html. You can either move your PHP to the /var/www/html folder or change the default folder as per the link above. I suspect that changing the default may have repercussions to future versions as they will be expecting code to reside in /var/www/html.

There will also be some permissions issues for that folder that you may wish to be aware of if you are copying into and creating sub folders.

Hope this is of use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

you may have version changes between the machines.

on ubuntu, you can check the file /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

to see what error was thrown.

To check for the current PHP version on your machine, you could use

```
php -v
```

from the command line (requires **php5-cli** module installed)

another way is to put a PHP file with:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

in your web dir, and open it with your browser.

Comment: Will do this and report back.

Comment: it looks to be the version difference between the live environment and the test environment. The perils of doing things on a shoestring :)

Comment: @jason did you manage to overcome your issue? It's a matter of syntax differences

Comment: I did and it was indeed to do with the versions. Rather than changing the code, I updated the version on the server to match the test environment as per this link http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-5-3-php-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts/  Another lesson learned as I hadn't even considered the PHP version. I guess you have all experienced the same at some point, and hence knew the answer :)

Comment: @jason great to hear. Please Consider upvoting/accepting my answer if it helped you